# Web Audio Mobile Safari Lock Screen Controls

Tags: mobile-safari, web-audio-api, soundmanager2

I have a web audio player that uses Soundmanager2.  Right now play/pause work on the lock screen and prev/next do not work.  I worked on iOS 7 but I couldn't figure out why.

I see lots of talk about setting the track image and player controls in a native app, but not in an audio web app.  That said I'd like to know why it quit working in iOS8 and what I can do to add a track image?

Update: Controls do not work in iOS 8, only on iOS7.

Comment: Got any news on this one?

Comment: Nope, haven't heard anything.

Comment: Would be cool to know the status. haven't tested since, but I guess it's still status quo. This kind of functionality is probably more meant for the normal native app interface - Apple earns big buck on not letting apps bypass the app store ofcourse

Comment: Hello from the future. Any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/download/:

Side note: The prior release's pre-emptive fix for iOS 8 ended up being a non-issue, as the official iOS 8 release did not use "OS 10" in the user-agent string. Nonetheless, SoundManager2 will now correctly identify iOS 10+ vs. incorrectly flagging it as "iOS 1".

Since this question was asked Mar 21 '14 at 20:20, and the heading above it was 
 "version = "V2.97a.20150601"" (6/1/15), which means the update came after this question, and the edit, so 
 it should be able to work now.